# Creating a file anyone can write to, but limiting who can read it

Tags: linux, file, attributes

Running Linux 2.6 kernel, is there any way to create a file with write permission for all but with read for only owner and group.  We need to update a log file but only allow the owner (usually root) and group to read the data in it (security).

Comment: `chmod 0662 filename`?

Answer (score 1):

This is allowable in the base unix permissions model. You can have a file you can write too but not read back from it. For the file itself the following permissions allow all users to write to the file.

```
touch logfile.log
chmod 662 logfile.log
ls -al
-rw-rw--w-  1 mmcgarrah mmcgarrah  0 Aug 19 17:15 logfile.log
```

Permissions to enter the directory containing the file are your other concern.  Make sure that non-owners can traverse to the file or they will not be able to see the file to write to it.

Write permission however also grants delete access to the file so beware malicious users removing the file.